# How to execute a function on the right elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am templating a HUGO website with a list page with cards. I have audio files from content in each card. Here are the html elements :

```html
<audio class="podcast__audio" src="{{ $podcast.RelPermalink }}"></audio>
```

I have a button for each card to play audio :

```html
<button class="podcast__player_button">
    <img class="podcast__player_play" src="/images/podcast/play.png">
</button>
```

In Javascript I play audio with this function :

```js
const podcastAudio = document.querySelector('.podcast__audio');

function toggleAudio () {
  if (podcastAudio.paused) {
    podcastAudio.play();

  } else {
    podcastAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

I display 4 cards on the list page and each card has one different audio file to play.

I have a for loop for the event listener on the buttons :

```js
const podcastPlayerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.podcast__player_button');

for (let i = 0; i < podcastPlayerButton.length; i++) {
  podcastPlayerButton[i].addEventListener('click', toggleAudio);
}
```

It works fine but it toggles only the first audio file of the page (which makes sense) but I want it to play the audio file linked to each card. The first `podcast__player_button` button should play the first `podcast__audio` file, the second button should play the second audio file and so on.

I guess I need to `querySelectorAll` audio files and iterate on it ?
How to execute the `toggleAudio()` function on the right audio files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok because buttons and audio files have the same index this code works :

```js
for (let i = 0; i < podcastPlayerButton.length; i++) {
  podcastPlayerButton[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (podcastAudio[i].paused) {
      podcastAudio[i].play();
    } else {
      podcastAudio[i].pause();
    }
  })
};
```